# Crash (program not responding) when median evaluates to zero (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, crash, median, percentile

I have a problem with Excel 2010 crashing (Windows XP says Excel is "not responding") when I use VBA to calculate the median of an array, in cases where the median function evaluates to zero. Unfortunately the problem is reproducible only in the context of a particular set of code (when I try to write simplified version, for debugging, the problem does not occur). Nevertheless, I think someone ma find this problem interesting for the following reasons.

The crash happens while application.worksheetfunction.median is being called. VBA cannot get past that call. It is not a problem of subsequently diving by zero.

The crash happens even if the array is very small (e.g., 8).

I've found that an effective workaround is for me to add a small constant to each array item, then calculate the median, then immediately subtract the constant from each array value. This appears to produce a correct answer. But it worries me that Excel requires this workaround.

The problem also occurs with another worksheet function that involves sorting: the percentile function.

Comment: I can't duplicate the problem. Can you post the code that produces the problem?

Comment: Sorry. The URL got mis-formatted. Here's a re-try.  http://www.bgsu.edu/departments/psych/faculty/randers/temp/median%20problem.xlsm

Comment: @CharlesWilliams Thanks for your interest. Since the problem involves the VBA code interacting with a spreadsheet, here is a URL where you can download the entire xlsm file: http://www.bgsu.edu/departments/psych/faculty/randers/temp/median%20problem.xlsm  (I will also try to figure out how to use the markdown formatting to include just the code, here on stackoverflow.)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I can now duplicate the problem. Looks like a bug in Excel 2010 to me. Narrowing it down it looks like a bug related to floating point problems with extremely small numbers in Median: for instance you can bypass the problem by addin a zero to

```
tempCrossZ(i) = tempA(i) * tempB(i)
```

to make

```
tempCrossZ(i) = tempA(i) * tempB(i) + 0#
```

before calling MEDIAN.
If you will allow it I will report this as a bug to the Excel team using your test file.

Comment: Thanks!. And yes, please send-in the code and report it as a bug. Also, I have already gotten around the bug by re-doing my program so that all statistical calculations are done on spreadsheet cell ranges rather than on arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I have been getting the same problem under similar conditions -- except in Excel 2003, and only when calculating an array of type Double or Single. That is, Excel just hangs (no response) when calculating the median of an array, when the "answer" to the calculation is zero.

Same when calculating the percentile or trimmean functions of an array.

If I write the array to a range, then use a formula ("=MEDIAN(myRng)" etc.) for the calculation, Excel doesn't freeze. Only when calculating an array of type Double or Single. (Excel doesn't seem to mind if I use Long; haven't tried Integer.)

I've used a workaround as suggested above:

```
For i = 1 To UBound(myArr)
    ratioArr(i) = ratioArr(i) + 0#
Next i
```

{my calculations here, then:}

```
For i = 1 To UBound(myArr)
    ratioArr(i) = ratioArr(i) - 0#
Next i
```

Seems to work, as a kludge. (But shows that I need to migrate off Excel for any serious statistical work. Time to finally learn C++, I guess, or cry tryin'.)